# How to match the closest pattern on a capture group excluding overlap?

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to match `text`, and I have a pattern like `/<a.*?href\s*=\s*["\']([^"\'>]+)["\'][^>]*>[\s\S]*?(text)[\s\S]*?<\/a>/gi`, how can I grab only the inner `<a ...> text </a>` when I am given `<a ...> <a ...> ... text ... </a> </a>` ? the `...` means it could be anything.

I know using regex on html probably is not the best idea, but using a DOM parser is pretty slow.

Edit 1: Example input: `<a href="cbc.com"><a href="google.com"> <span>text</span> </a></a>`, Desired output: `<a href="google.com"> <span>text</span> </a>`, currently using `/<a.*?href\s*=\s*["\']([^"\'>]+)["\'][^>]*>[\s\S]*?(text)[\s\S]*?<\/a>/gi` will match `<a href="cbc.com"><a href="google.com"> <span>text</span> </a>`

Comment: not clear, give possible input and ouput.

Comment: thanks, edited and provided input and output

Comment: `foo(?:(?!foo).)*?xyz.*?bar` is the formula